# Preguntas dentro de preguntas: ¿Debemos escribir doble signo de interrogación al transcribir una pregunta dentro de otra pregunta?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación, preguntas

Consideremos el siguiente ejemplo:

> ¿Quieres que le pregunte directamente... ¿Cuántos años tienes??

Se explica por sí solo. ¿Debemos escribir doble signo de interrogación cuando queremos, por ejemplo, transcribir una pregunta dentro de otra pregunta?

Otras opciones que se me ocurren es que no esté permitido escribir preguntas dentro de preguntas y que por tanto deba escribirse como:

> ¿Quieres que le pregunte directamente... Cuántos años tienes?

O que no deba ponerse doble ??:

> ¿Quieres que le pregunte directamente... ¿Cuántos años tienes?

Comment: Podrías evitar el doble signo utilizando comillas: _¿Quieres que le pregunte directamente... "¿Cuántos años tienes?"?_. En cuanto a los signos anidados, no encuentro referencias en el [DPD - interrogación y exclamación (signos de)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bH8aKhoE1D6eF5Wp4C)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fundéu lo resolvió hace un tiempo:

> **[interrogación (duplicación)](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/interrogacion-duplicacion/)**
>
> Pregunta: Tengo un título de una película que es una pregunta y va dentro de otra pregunta: «¿Has podido ver ¿Quién es el culpable? ?». Me han dicho que eso es incorrecto y que debo suprimir una de las interrogaciones, pero lo veo raro. ¿Existe tal norma ortográfica?
>
> ---
>
> Respuesta: Tal como lo ha escrito es correcto, como también sería correcto, digamos, «*¿¿Quién es el culpable? te gustó?*». Es posible que quieran evitar dos signos iguales juntos o que haya uno en redonda pegado a otro en cursiva (porque se puedan superponer ligeramente, aunque con los medios actuales reajustar este posible problema es fácil).
>
> Hay que señalar que el ortotipógrafo José Martínez de Sousa y, para el inglés, el manual de estilo de Chicago sí proponen la supresión de la segunda interrogación, pero no es realmente necesario e incluso puede resultar desconcertante que haya un signo de apertura que no tiene el correspondiente de cierre.

---

El [comentario de Yay](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17125/preguntas-dentro-de-preguntas#comment22928_17126) me hizo ver que la respuesta no es lo suficientemente completa, pues solo se refiere a este caso completo. Impelido por el ejemplo de Carlos Alejo, también escribí a la RAE consultándoselo. He aquí su respuesta:

> En principio, no puede darse el caso de que aparezcan seguidos dos signos de interrogación de cierre pertenecientes a distintas preguntas. O bien la pregunta que se incluye dentro de otra se introduce como texto citado y, por tanto, debe aparecer entre comillas, o bien se trata de una interrogativa indirecta, y, por tanto se debe escribir sin signos de interrogación.
>
> Si no entendemos mal el ejemplo que propone, parece que en él la pregunta ¿Cuántos años tienes? se presenta como texto citado, es decir, como una pregunta ya hecha que se menciona. Si esto es así, debe escribirse entre comillas, con lo que los dos signos de interrogación de cierre quedan separados por las comillas de cierre: ¿Quieres que le pregunte directamente... «¿Cuántos años tienes?»?
>
> Otra opción sería considerar la pregunta como interrogativa indirecta, pero en ese caso el verbo de esta interrogativa debería aparecer en tercera persona en su ejemplo: *¿Quieres que le pregunte directamente... cuántos años tiene?*
>
> También podría darse el caso de que el título de una película, por ejemplo, fuera una pregunta y, por tanto, si apareciera al final de otra pregunta, nos encontraríamos con dos signos seguidos. No obstante, en ese caso, el signo de interrogación de cierre que forma parte del título de la película aparecería en cursiva:
>
> > ¿Has visto *¿Quién engañó a Roger Rabbit?*?
>
> Para terminar, es conveniente indicar que, sin ser incorrectos, en todos estos ejemplos se obtienen resultados tipográficamente extraños, que conviene evitar en la medida de lo posible.

Comment: Pero en ese caso *¿Quién es el culpable?* es una película, por lo que se deja como tal. En la pregunta, *¿Cuántos años tienes?* es una cita en estilo directo, por lo que se debería escribir entrecomillada: ¿Quieres que le pregunte directamente... "¿Cuántos años tienes?"?, o: ¿Quieres que le pregunte directamente "¿Cuántos años tienes?"?, o incluso: ¿Quieres que le pregunte directamente "¿cuántos años tienes?"?

Comment: Cierto, @Yay . Debo incluir la referencia que hice en los comentarios a la pregunta al hecho de que la RAE no es explícita al respecto. También quiero consultarles directamente para ver si hay alguna referencia que se me escapa. Lo que me parece útil de la página de Fundéu es lo que menciona al final del segundo párrafo: _puede resultar desconcertante que haya un signo de apertura que no tiene el correspondiente de cierre_. No es norma, sino algo así como sentido común. Cuando pueda actualizaré.

Comment: @Yay consulté con la RAE. Actualicé con su respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Este hipotético jamás sucede en la práctica y, como dice la RAE, se considera interrogativa indirecta: «¿Quieres que le pregunte [que] cuántos años tiene?», con ese «que» siendo una partícula opcional (al menos en mexicano) y el «cuántos» acentuado denotando la interrogativa, sin necesidad de anidar un segundo par de signos de interrogación.