# ¿Signos de interrogación dentro de otros?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

Quiero escribir la siguiente pregunta:

> ¿Cómo se dice "¿Cuál es la parte delantera? ¿Cuál es la parte trasera?" en inglés?

No entiendo. ¿Está bien? ¿Debería ir entre comillas? De ser así, ¿Las comillas irían en cada pregunta o como está el ejemplo, en toda la frase? ¿No debería ir entre comillas?

Comment: Me parece correcta tu puntuación.  (Quoting direct speech.)  Quizás el otro estilo de comillas sería preferible pero yo en lo personal siempre uso " " (por flojera), así que para mí se puede quedar así.

Comment: Sobre la parte de pregunta dentro de pregunta: sí, es correcto usarlas *anidadas*. Véase [Preguntas dentro de preguntas: ¿Debemos escribir doble signo de interrogación al transcribir una pregunta dentro de otra pregunta?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17125/1674).